# SELECT takes too long

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-2008, select

I need your help :)

I have a table in a database (SQL Server 2008 R2). Currently there are around 4M rows.

Consumer apps take rows from there (lock them and process).

To protect rows from being taken by more than one consumer I'm locking it by adding some flag into appropriate column...

So, to "lock" record I do

```
SELECT TOP 1  .....
```

and then `UPDATE` operation on record with some specific ID.

This operation takes up to 5 seconds now (I tried in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM testdb.dbo.myTable 
WHERE recordLockedBy is NULL;
```

How can I speed it up?

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[num] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL,
[field1] [varchar](150) NULL,
[field2] [varchar](150) NULL,
[field3] [varchar](150) NULL,
[field4] [varchar](150) NULL,
[date2] [datetime] NULL,
[recordLockedBy] [varchar](100) NULL,
[timeLocked] [datetime] NULL,
[field5] [varchar](100) NULL);
```

Comment: don't do a `select *`, its faster to explicitly list your columns even if you want all of them.

Comment: @Muad'Dib while I agree 100% with the sentiment, and blog and speak about it often (e.g. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), the difference in speed - if you really do need all of the columns - is so absolutely miniscule that it doesn't exist for all intents and purposes. This argument is like saying a drop of water on your car hood will impact aerodynamics and lead to worse gas mileage. While academically true, it is hard to prove (and much, much harder to justify getting out and wiping it off).

Comment: @Aaron I agree entirely - with obvious exceptions of a large BLOB/CLOB/XML/etc column that would swamp the connection but isn't wanted

Comment: @Marc right, which is why I qualified with *if you really do need all of the columns* :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I think that advice is perhaps out-dated. I've just performed a test against a table with 1.5million records and the execution plan (and costs) were identical for both `SELECT TOP 1 *` and `SELECT TOP 1 {Column List}` queries.

Comment: @Rob the difference I am talking about is not something you would see in the plan, and that I hoped I explained would not be noticeable in the comparison of two queries. Which was my whole point in leaving a comment - I agree with you that when selecting all columns, the performance aspect is negligible. However there are other reasons to not use SELECT * (e.g. forward compatibility). And there definitely *will* be a performance difference if `{Column List}` is smaller than `*` and the optimizer could have used a narrower index, avoided lookups, etc. if you hadn't used `*`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you stated "its faster to explicitly list your columns **even if you want all of them**" and I refuted that by testing that hypothesis and finding it to be false. If it's "not noticeable in the comparison of two queries" then **it's not faster**. The performance aspect is not "negligible", it's non-existant. Forward compatibility and column subsets are an entirely different kettle of fish (and I agree entirely as far as forward compatibility is concerned!).

Comment: @Rob please take a closer look at the comment you're quoting. I stated no such thing, that was Muad'Dib. I said I agree with the sentiment (e.g. never use `SELECT *`), but not his reason *in the case where all columns are needed anyway*. There *is* a miniscule performance hit when you say `SELECT *` which has to do with deriving column metadata that is only slightly different than validating column names. In terms of overall query cost it is as close to zero as it can be, but it is not accurate to say it doesn't exist. In practical terms, sure, but in academic terms, I will have to disagree.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - arse, my apologies. I intended to address my initial comment at Muad'Dib and for some reason (best known to what passes for my brain) I mixed you two up.

Comment: @Rob that's ok. My point still stands though: a negligible difference and a non-existent difference are not the same thing.  You could take your hypothesis to Conor Cunningham, who might know a thing or two about the optimizer. He will gladly tell you that yes there is an underlying difference between `SELECT *` and `SELECT {all columns}` but, as I have already tried to explain, the difference is so small it would never affect the metrics around a query in real life (and it is not something that is exposed in the execution plan).

Comment: @Rob  Of course, he might be equally likely to tell you, stop worrying about this difference because it absolutely doesn't matter to your query. Go focus on your indexes or schema instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes should be placed on any columns you use in your query's where clause. Therefore you should add an index to `recordLockedBy`.

If you don't know about indexes look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I just added an Index on that column. Do I have to refresh table data somehow to see index in work? Now after creating index I didn't see any faster results.

Answer (score 0):

Quicker starter for you:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD INDEX IDX_myTable_recordLockedBy (recordLockedBy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your select statement query by id as well?  If so, this should be set as a primary key with a clustered index (the default for PKs I believe).  SQL will then be able to jump directly to the record - should be near instant.  Without it will do a table scan looking at every record in the sequence they appear on disk until it finds the one you're after.

Comment: I believe `Identity` columns are primary key.

Comment: I'm not sure that they are.  This wiki article says they aren't http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column.  I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Ash while IDENTITY columns *can* be the primary key, and often are, this is correlation but not causality. It is absolutely feasible to have an IDENTITY column that is not a primary key, a primary key that is not clustered, a primary key that is clustered but is on column(s) other than the IDENTITY column, or an IDENTITY column that has a clustered index but is not the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This won't prevent a race condition on the table and allow the same row to be processed by multiple consumers.

Look at UPDLOCK and READPAST locking hints to handle this case:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/

Answer (score -1):

If the table is used for job scheduling and processing, perhaps you can use MSMQ to solve this problem. You don't need to worry about locking and things like that. It also scales much better on enterprise, and has many different send/received modes.

You can learn more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hardly applies to the question, does it?